# Is it possible to change the Closed Date of a user story in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops

I'd like to change the date of my story, which was finished in order to keep my Burn-down chart consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid this is currently not possible in azure devops . The field `Closed Date`
(Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate) is read only, we cannot change it.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions.After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.